# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-d"

Tags: python, tkinter

I made an account just to ask a question but I think I need an account anyways because I use this site a lot. I have a question I get this error:

`_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-d"`

**Here is the whole error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rogeram/PycharmProjects/Calculator/calculator.py", line 254, in <module>
    command=added_value.cos).grid(row=1, column=5, pady=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-d"
```

**Here is the code:**

```
def cos(self):
    self.result = False
    self.current = math.cos(math.radians(float(txtDisplay.get())))
    self.display(self.current)
```

and:

```
btnCos = Button(calc, text="cos", width=6, height=2, font=('arial',20, 'bold'), d=4, bg="powder blue",
            command=added_value.cos).grid(row=1, column=5, pady=1)
```

Thank you in advance. I've been knocking my head on this error. I looked at other similar errors but I couldn't figure it out.

The expected result: To not give me an error and the program actually runs.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add more code to the question? It is impossible to debug an error without knowing the context. If `command=added_value.cos` is the error source, what is `added_value`?

Comment: I think you want `bd=4` instead of `d=4` in `btnCos = Button(..., d=4, ...)`.

Comment: Hey I can't upvote for some reason It won't let I already tried many times. It says I need more points or something like that.

Comment: Yeah; you need at least 15 points to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to this:

```
btnCos = Button(..., d=4, ...).grid(...)
```

`d` is not a supported option of the `Button` widget. You need to remove that option, or replace it with a valid option.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I meant to put bd=4 not just d no wonder it didn't work!! such a headache for a small mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

You use `d=` when defining a `Button`. `d` is not an accepted setting for `Button`. [These](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#setting-options) are the accepted settings

Comment: OMG thank you I meant to write bd=4 not just d. wow I can't believe this lol